# How to extract memnet heat maps with the caffe model?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, heatmap, caffe

I want to extract both memorability score and memorability heat maps by using the available memnet caffemodel by Khosla et al. at [link](http://memorability.csail.mit.edu/download.html)
Looking at the prototxt model, I can understand that the final inner-product output should be the memorability score, but how should I obtain the memorability map for a given input image? [Here](https://phys.org/news/2015-12-deep-learning-algorithm-photos-near-human.html) some examples.

Thanks in advance

Comment: They describe how to get a heatmap in their paper, see section 5.

Comment: so I should feed image patches to the CNN, take the fc activations and transform them to obtain the corresponding heatmap patches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in their paper [1], the CNN (MemNet) outputs a single, real-valued output for the memorability. So, the network they made [publicly available](http://memorability.csail.mit.edu/download.html), calculates this single memorability score, given an input image - and not a heatmap.

In section 5 of the paper, they describe how to use this trained CNN to predict a memorability heatmap:

> To generate memorability maps, we simply scale up the image and apply MemNet to overlapping regions of the image. We do this for multiple scales of the image and average the resulting memorability maps.

Let's consider the two important steps here:

#### Problem 1: Make the CNN work with any input size.

To make the CNN work on images of any arbitrary size, they use the method presented in [2].
While convolutional layers can be applied to images of arbitrary size - resulting in smaller or larger outputs - the inner product layers have a fixed input and output size.
To make an inner product layer work with any input size, you apply it just like a convolutional kernel. For an FC layer with 4096 outputs, you interpret it as a 1x1 convolution with 4096 feature maps.

To do that in Caffe, you can directly follow the [Net Surgery tutorial](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb). You create a new `.prototxt` file, where you replace the `InnerProduct` layers with `Convolution` layers. Now, Caffe won't recognize the weights in the `.caffemodel` anymore, as the layer types don't match anymore. So, you load the old net and its parameters into Python, load the new net, and assign the old parameters to the new net and save it as a new `.caffemodel` file.

Now, we can run images of any dimensions (larger or equal than 227x227) through the network.

#### Problem 2: Generate the heat map

As explained in the paper [1], you apply this fully-convolutional network from Problem 1 to the same image at different scales. The MemNet is a re-trained AlexNet, so the default input dimension is 227x227. They mention that a 451x451 input gives a 8x8 output, which implies a stride of 28 for applying the layers. So a simple example could be:

- Scale 1: 227x227 → 1x1. (I guess they definitely use this scale.)
- Scale 2: 283x283 → 2x2. (Wild guess)
- Scale 3: 339x339 → 4x4. (Wild guess)
- Scale 4: 451x451 → 8x8. (This scale is mentioned in the paper.)

The results will look like this:

[image: multi-res]

So, you'll just average these outputs to get your final 8x8 heatmap. From the image above, it should be clear how to average the different-scale outputs: you'll have to upsample the low-res ones to 8x8, and average then.

From the paper, I assume that they use very high-res scales, so their heatmap will be around the same size as the image initially was. They write that it takes 1s on a "normal" GPU. This is a quite long time, which also indicates that they probably upsample the input images quite to quite high dimensions.

#### Bibliography:

[1]: A. Khosla, A. S. Raju, A. Torralba, and A. Oliva, "Understanding and Predicting Image Memorability at a Large Scale", in: ICCV, 2015. [[PDF]](http://people.csail.mit.edu/khosla/papers/iccv2015_khosla.pdf)
[2]: J. Long, E. Shelhamer, and T. Darrell, "Fully convolutional networks for semantic segmentation", in: CVPR, 2015. [[PDF]](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf)

Comment: According the formula, the image dimensions to obtain a 227x227 map should be 7226x7226.

Comment: I've done points 1 and 2 with caffenet. Taking as output the "prob" blob (8x8). However, the memnet architecture ends with an fc8-euclidean, and there is not any prob blob. The fc6 and fc7 have a dimension of (10, 4096, 8, 8). In which can I find my heatmap?

Comment: MemNet is not exactly the same as CaffeNet: they removed CaffeNet's `prob` and `fc8` layers, and replaced them by a new layer `fc8-euclidean` which gives you one single output. If you want to train a new MemNet-like CNN from scratch, then you should do the same, and train this new `fc8-euclidean` layer. If you don't want to train, but only apply the MemNet, you should use their prototxt and caffemodel files.